# Confusion about JdbcTemplate.update

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I've come across a rather confusing issue about JdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes). I'm working on a web application and in my userDao's add and update methods, I have the following code:

userDao.addUser

```
public int addUser(User user) {
    String sql = "insert into users (firstName, lastName, username) values (?, ?, ?)";

    Object[] args = {
            user.getFirstName(),
            user.getLastName(),
            user.getUsername()
    };
    int[] types = {VARCHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR};

    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, args, types);
}
```

userDao.update

```
public int update(User user) {
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("update users ");
    ArrayList<Integer> typesList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> argsList = new ArrayList<>();

    if ((user.getFirstName() != null) && (!user.getFirstName().equals(""))) {
        sql.append("set firstName = ? ");
        typesList.add(VARCHAR);
        argsList.add(user.getFirstName());
    } else if ((user.getLastName() != null) && (!user.getLastName().equals(""))) {
        sql.append("set lastName = ? ");
        typesList.add(VARCHAR);
        argsList.add(user.getLastName());
    } else if ((user.getUsername() != null) && (!user.getUsername().equals(""))) {
        sql.append("set username = ? ");
        typesList.add(VARCHAR);
        argsList.add(user.getUsername());
    }

    sql.append("where userID = ?");
    typesList.add(INTEGER);
    argsList.add(user.getUserID());

    Integer[] types = typesList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    Object[] args = argsList.toArray();
    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql.toString(), args);
//  return jdbcTemplate.update(sql.toString(), args, types);
}
```

I spend hours searching SO and other forums for a solution, but nothing matched my problem. Technically, the code above works fine, but it's more of a lack of understanding of why this snippet works (the args parameter is from the above code, for brevity):

snippet 1:

```
int[] types = {VARCHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR};
return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, args, types);
```

and why this doesn't:

snippet 2:

```
Integer[] types = typesList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
return jdbcTemplate.update(sql.toString(), args, types);
```

Thing is, snippet 2 doesn't have any compile nor runtime error, but the update doesn't happen, until i remove the third parameter, as illustrated above.

In IntelliJ, the integrated documentation shows the javadoc for snippet 1 with the 3 parameters (which is what i expect), but in snippet 2, the javadoc is for the wrong update method (it shows the javadoc for public int update(String sql, Object... args) throws org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException instead).

The only clue I derived was possibly due to autoboxing/unboxing. Can anyone else shed light on this?

Comment: An `Integer[]` cannot be auto boxed to an `int[]` auto boxing is only for individual values not collections or arrays. That is also the reason why you get the javadoc for the method taking a varargs.

Comment: So does that also explain why when i ctrl-click the update method in snippet 2, it takes me to the wrong method as well? I figured the third parameter would be unboxed...is there a better way to write the code in the userDao.update than what I have above?

Comment: That is what I explained in my comment... DOn't specify the types and just pass the `args` as a vararg not as a `Object[]`. The template is smart enough to figure out the types himself.